# Jquery on keyup not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input and an event handler attached to it and for some reason, the keyup event is not working. I have looked at this a while and can't figure out what the problem is. The alert window is not even showing as I type something into the input box.

```
$(function () {
    var tagField = $("#<%= EditTagNum.ClientID %>"); //asp.net code to get the generated client ID

    $(tagField).on('keyup paste cut', function () {
        alert('inside event handler');
        var _this = this;
        //because the paste event fires before the text has actually been
        //pasted, I have to set a timeout. Once the timeout occurs, the text
        //has then been entered into the input box.
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(_this).val();
            $(_this).val(text.replace(/\D/g, ''));
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

---

**Update:**
I changed my code to use the generated client id directly as so:

> $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EditTagNum").on(.....

This did not solve the problem. BUT  I did discover that once I run my event handler function in the console, then it works. It is if the event handler is never attached. Yet, when I am debugging in chrome I see that it reaches the function to attach the handler. It just never gets inside of it.

Comment: Used your code here and tried a static element id for the jQuery selector: http://jsfiddle.net/SZG9B/ Looks like it works fine. Check and be sure that the argument/element you're passing to jQuery is valid/exists.

Comment: If the alert isn't firing, you either have syntax errors, or you're not getting the right selector from the serverside code.

Comment: Do `console.log(tagField.length)` after `var tagField = ...` to see if the element was found. Also, `tagField` is already a jquery object, you don't need to do `$(tagField)`

Comment: I updated my question with some additional information. @JasonP and yes tagField.length returned 1.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the id `EditTagNum`, like within a repeater? Do you have an `UpdatePanel` that could be refreshing the `EditTagNum` element/control?

Comment: What about binding the `.on` method to the document instead, allowing the three events originating from `tagField` to bubble all the way up? i.e. `$(document).on('keyup paste cut', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EditTagNum' ,function () {`

Comment: @JasonP No other elements have ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EditTagNum as an ID. There object is not being destroyed and recreated with an update panel. I was typing in tagField into the console throughout my debugging process to insure it still pointed to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if this works:

```
$(tagField).keyup(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(tagField).on('keyup paste cut', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var tagField = $("#<%= EditTagNum.ClientID %>");
```

Here **tagField is itself a jquery object**. And you are wrapping this object again in jquery. Try following :

```
 tagField.on('keyup paste cut', function () {
        alert('inside event handler');
        var _this = this;
        //because the paste event fires before the text has actually been
        //pasted, I have to set a timeout. Once the timeout occurs, the text
        //has then been entered into the input box.
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(_this).val();
            $(_this).val(text.replace(/\D/g, ''));
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this : 'keyup paste cut', try this ..  "keyup paste cut" ..
Worked for me magically in past ... ! :)

Comment: Using double or single quotes should not make a difference — it's more of a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).on('keyup', tagField, function() {...});
```

instead, if you are not sure that tagField is attached to the DOM at the time that you call $(tagField).on('keyup', tagfield, ...);